# JPA database delimiters

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have a two entity classes called User and Group, both reserved words that need to be delimited in order for the database to accept them as tables. Annotating the entities with:

```
@Table(name = "\"USER\"")
```

does the trick, but I read that EclipseLink allows you to specify a global that automatically delimits names. According to http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg03434.html, you need to include the following in orm.xml:

```
<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <delimited-identifiers/>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
```

I have annotated my classes however, and do not have an orm.xml, only a persistence.xml, where, according to the same source, I cannot include that property. Is there anywhere else I can specify:

```
eclipselink.database.delimiters = true
```

when the actual entity manager is being injected through @PersistenceContext?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Thanks James. I ended up with the following `orm.xml` and it does the trick perfectly!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit-metadata>
    <persistence-unit-defaults>
        <delimited-identifiers/>
    </persistence-unit-defaults>
</persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add an orm.xml, it only needs to have this setting, you can still define all of your mappings in annotations.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my original question to include the final code.